# Remove trailing date time and number from a filename with AppleScript

Tags: shell, applescript

I have to adjust a lot of files to remove the last part of them:

From this:
`108595-1121_gemd_u65_stpetenowopen_em_f_2021-12-03T161809.511773.zip`

To this:
`108595-1121_gemd_u65_stpetenowopen_em_f.zip`

It's always 24 characters that need to be stripped and there is always an underscore at the beginning. The rest is random numbers and characters. I found code below to remove numbers, but I need characters.

My goal is to put this in an automator script with some other processes, but the Renamer in Automator isn't robust enough.

How can I have it strip X-number of characters?

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    repeat with thisFile in input
        tell application "Finder"
            set {theName, theExtension} to {name, name extension} of thisFile
            if theExtension is in {missing value, ""} then
                set theExtension to ""
            else
                set theExtension to "." & theExtension
            end if
            set theName to text 1 thru -((count theExtension) + 1) of theName -- the name part
            set theName to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theName & " | sed 's/[0-9]*$//'") -- strip trailing numbers
            set name of thisFile to theName & theExtension
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `do shell script` here, which just confuses the issue. Since your names are underscore-delimited, just use AppleScript's `text item delimiters`:

```
repeat with thisFile in input
    tell application "Finder"
        set {theName, theExtension} to {name, name extension} of thisFile
        set tid to my text item delimiters
        set my text item delimiters to "_"
        set nameParts to text items of theName
        set revisedNameParts to items 1 through -2 of nameParts
        set newName to revisedNameParts as text
        set my text item delimiters to tid
        if theExtension is not in {missing value, ""} then 
            set newName to newName & "." & theExtension
        end if
        set name of thisFile to newName
    end tell
end repeat

return input
```

What this does, in words:

- lines 4 and 5 first save the current text item delimiter (TID) value and then set it to '_'
- line 6 breaks the name-*string* into a *list* of string parts by cutting the name string at the character '_'
- line 7 drops the last item in that *list* (which is everything after the last '_')
- line 8 reverses the process, combining the shortened *list* of text items into a single *string* by joining them with '_'
- The remainder resets the TID value to its original state, adds the extension to the string, and changes the file name

Comment: Wow. That was perfect! Can you explain a bit about how it was selecting it? Since there are several underscores, how does it know not to remove all of them? Or how many characters?

Comment: I've modified the answer with an explanation.

Comment: You've outdone yourself! Thank you so SO much!!!!